# How to Set ViewBox Image Source in Code Behind

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, viewbox

In following a code sample here [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752301(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752301%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) I'd like to be able to change the following XAML code to C# and set the ViewBox source in code behind. What is the proper method of doing this? Must I set the Child of the ViewBox?

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Viewbox MaxWidth="500" MaxHeight="500" Name="vb1">
        <Image Source="tulip_farm.jpg"/>
    </Viewbox>    
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Give the ViewBox a name and you will be able to access it by that name in the code behind. `Name="vbTulipFarm"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is give a name to that specific image so you can set the source anywhere you want in code:

```
         <Image x:Name="MyImage" Source="tulip_farm.jpg"/>
```

And in c#:

```
        BitmapImage bitimg = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/MyNewLink.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
        MyImage.Source = bitimg as ImageSource;
```

Comment: Makes sense. A slightly different implementation than what I was thinking but it should work!

Comment: Is there a way to set the background of a `ViewBox` if the user does not have an image selected? Or must I do something like show a default image?